# Non static variable cannot be referenced

Tags: java, program-entry-point, non-static

I'm trying to make the code in my main() method as light as possible by dividing the code in multiple function, so for example I create an instance of a class RentalAgency with the following function :

```
/** Creates an Agency with some cars and motorbikes
  */
  public RentalAgency createAgency(){
    List<Vehicle> theVehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
    Map<Client,Vehicle> rentedVehicles = new HashMap <Client,Vehicle>();
    RentalAgency agency = new RentalAgency(theVehicles, rentedVehicles);
    Vehicle v1 = new Vehicle("Renault","clio",1998,50);
    agency.addVehicle(v1);
    Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle("Renault","twingo",2000,40);
    agency.addVehicle(v2);
    Car c1 = new Car("Renault","scenic",2005, 80, 7);
    agency.addVehicle(c1);
    Car c2 = new Car("Citroen","c3",2006, 70, 5);
    agency.addVehicle(c2);
    MotorBike m1 = new MotorBike("Honda","CB",2015, 50, 500);
    agency.addVehicle(m1);
    MotorBike m2 = new MotorBike("Yamaha","MT",2017, 80, 750);
    agency.addVehicle(m2);
    return agency;
  }
```

And in the main() I try to run this :

```
/**The main function to run the Agency and some renting
  */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownVehicleException {
      RentalAgency agency = this.createAgency();
    }
```

but I get an error like so :

> error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
>         RentalAgency agency = this.createAgency();

Which I don't really know how to correct, I looked it up and it seems to occurs when you try to use a method on something that is not initiated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` in java refers to the object which you have in hand. Now, in your case there is no object just the reference of RentalAgency in main method.

To use `this`, you need to create an object. But, I am guessing you are using `createAgency` method for that instead of the usual constructor approach. So, mark the `createAgency` as `static` and call it without using `this` from `main` method.

```
public static RentalAgency createAgency(){
   //Some code goes here
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownVehicleException 
{
  RentalAgency agency = createAgency();
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks ! :)

Comment: happy to help. If it helped, please accept the answer. :)

Comment: "this in java refers to the object which you have in hand"...  Eh, kind'a...  But there's still things like `OuterClass.this` from an inner class where this doesn't really ring true.

Answer (score 3):

Change the method signature to following:

```
public static RentalAgency createAgency() {...}
```

You also need to remove `this` referencing from the `main()` method and simply call the method in the following way:

```
RentalAgency agency = createAgency();
```

Comment: I'm not sure as to how is adding static to the declaration helping ?

Comment: You can't call a non-static method inside static `main()` method

Comment: in addition to adding static, you need to remove this from main method.

Answer (score 0):

main() is a static function, so there is no instance `this` to be referenced from within. Try making `createAgency()` static:

```
public static RentalAgency createAgency() {
    ...
}
```